# Jquery image cycling issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I'm working on a website for a family friend. On it they wanted to have logos from all their associates on one row, that subtly fade to get replaced with additional logos that didn't fit the first time.

To achieve this i've assigned the `<img>`'s classes, that represent what cycle they should appear in, depending on how many of those images will fit on the row given its current width. This happens in my `assignCycleNumbers` function.

Then to actually fade them in and out i have another function called `cycleAssociates` which recursively fades the appropriate classes in and out. Well in theory, however it doesn't seem to be working properly, which is particularly odd because [i tested the function here](http://jsfiddle.net/BvLb4/14/) and it works fine. The only difference between them is that now i'm trying to assign the cycle numbers dynamically.

I'm really stumped and could do with some help!

You can see the [website hosted here](http://c3it.webuda.com/) and if you scroll down to the bottom of the content you'll see the logos at the bottom, not behaving as expected. (First cycle appears okay but then subsequent cycles get muddled, more observable if you resize to a smaller screen width).

You can inspect the code thoroughly through your browser but here's everything you need to know, again i'd really appreciate any insight.

**EDIT**: [The whole javascript file as requested.](http://pastebin.com/nSxPJiXM) But all the relevant stuff is below:

**JS:**

```
//single global variable to represent how many logo cycles there is
var totalCycles = 0;

...

$(window).load(function() {

    ...
   totalCycles = assignCycleNumbers();
   cycleAssociates();


});

// window is resized 
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function() {
        ...
        totalCycles = assignCycleNumbers();
    });
});

...

function cycleAssociates(){
    var cycle = 0;

    var recursiveCycling = function(cycle, totalCycles){
        var currentAssociate = ".cycle" + cycle;
        //fade in all img with the current cyle class over a second,
        //wait 3 seconds before fading out over a second.
        $(currentAssociate).delay(100).fadeIn(1000).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000,
            function(){
                cycle++;
                if(cycle > totalCycles){
                    cycle = 0;
                }
                recursiveCycling(cycle, totalCycles);
            });

    };
    recursiveCycling(cycle, totalCycles);

}


function assignCycleNumbers(){
    //first remove any old cycle# classes (resized window case)
    $('[class*="cycle"]').removeClass( function(unusedIdx,c){
        return c.match(/cycle\d+/g).join(" ");
    });

    //measure div width
    var divSpace = $("#bodies").innerWidth();
    //assign a cycle number to a number of logos until no more will fit in that div
    var cycleNum = 0;
    $(".associate").each(function(){

        if( divSpace - $(this).width() > 0){
            $(this).addClass("cycle" + cycleNum);
            divSpace = divSpace - $(this).width();
        }
        else{ //next logo won't fit current cycle, create next cycle
            cycleNum++
            $(this).addClass("cycle" + cycleNum);
            divSpace = $("#bodies").innerWidth() - $(this).width();
        }
    });
    return cycleNum;
}
```

**html:**

```
                <img class="associate" src="IMG/spare.png" alt=""/>
                <img class="associate" src="IMG/bcs_professional.jpg" alt="BCS Professional Member"/>
                <img class="associate" src="IMG/climate_savers.jpg" alt="Climate Savers Smart Computing"/>
                <img class="associate" src="IMG/code_of_conduct.jpg" alt="Data Centres Code Of Conduct Endorser"/>
                <img class="associate" src="IMG/spare.gif" alt=""/>
                <img class="associate" src="IMG/enistic.gif" alt="Enistic"/>
                <img class="associate" src="IMG/greentrac_authorised.png" alt="Greentrac Authorised Reseller"/>
                <img class="associate" src="IMG/very_pc.jpg" alt="Very PC Approved"/>
                <img class="associate" src="IMG/spare.jpg" alt=""/>
```

**css:**

```
#bodies img.associate{
            float: left;
            max-width: 120px;
            max-height: 80px;
            display:none;
        }
```

Comment: +1 because I really really like the way you're doing this :)

Comment: Interestingly, I think it works on Google Chrome.

Comment: @Abody97 Thanks for the kind words! Actually im using google chrome and i'm not finding that it works.. but the test jsfiddle posted in the question does work! So it must be something to do with the way i'm assigning the cycle numbers or the totalCycle variable perhaps? but when i inspect the website that looks fine.. most perculiar. Thanks for taking the time to inspect it!

Comment: your javascript code in jsFiddle and in this post are different. please give us your whole code (fill ...s).

Comment: @DariushJafari, The jsfiddle was just supposed to be a demonstration that one of the functions definitely worked that i happend to do beforehand. I assumed people would access the pages javscript through their browser/browser extension if they wanted to see everything but you're quite right, i have added a pastebin link above :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your `fadeOut` function's callback is being executed even before all elements in the current cycle are faded out. Here's a modified version of your function that works as expected:

```
function cycleAssociates(){
    var cycle = 0;
    var recursiveCycling = function(cycle, totalCycles){
        var currentAssociate = ".cycle" + cycle;
        var n = $(currentAssociate).length; //How many images in current cycle?
        $(currentAssociate).each(function() {
            $(this).delay(100).fadeIn(1000).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
                n --;
                if(n <= 0) { //current cycle done?
                    cycle++;
                    if(cycle > totalCycles){
                        cycle = 0;
                    }
                    recursiveCycling(cycle, totalCycles);
                }
            });    
        });    
    };
    recursiveCycling(cycle, totalCycles);
}
```

To fix the issues that come up on window resize, try replacing your current `$(window).resize` handler with this:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function() {
        parallelNavbar();
        $(".associate").stop(); //if there are any animations, stop 'em
        $(".associate").hide(); //hide all associates
        totalCycles = assignCycleNumbers(); //update the assignment
        cycleAssociates(); //let's get cyclin' again!
    });
});
```

Although I think you have some issues with scrolling. This should resolve the main cycling problem, though -- so I hope that helped!

Comment: I never would have figured this out thank you so much! I do have one remaining problem, when i drag the window around to resize it i get inconsistant results, occasionally the script appears to stop working and nothing is shown, i think it seems to be happening the most when i maximise/un-maximise/use windows snap feature. Also when the width changes (eg shrinks with the window) but one cycle is still being shown that cycles images then fall onto a second row.. i didn't realise how non-trivial this approach would be! ha

Comment: @Holly Please check my updated answer with a suggested fix for that :)